# Disable MSBuild output of "Processing /ORDER options..."

Tags: c++, msbuild, build

The output file from our project build has gone from 6MB to over 75MB in text.

Diff'ing the last good build and the first time it blew up, there's a section in the output file like this in the latest:

```
Processing /ORDER options
External code objects not listed in the /ORDER file:
    ?onCallDisconnected@CallStateConnected@CallImpl@space@@UAEXV?$shared_ptr@VCallImpl@space@@@boost@@V?$shared_ptr@VGenericCall@space@@@5@K@Z                     ; framework.lib(CallStates.obj)
    ??_DBoolSetting@space@@QAEXXZ                             ; framework.lib(SettingValueImpl.obj)
```

...... continues for ~50MB

```
    ??$?0U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@J@std@@@?$allocator@U_Node@?$_Tree_nod@V?$_Tmap_traits@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@JU?$less@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@J@std@@@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@J@std@@@1@@Z                     ; CallStatistics.obj

 Finished processing /ORDER options
```

I'm not sure how this got in there, but anyone know how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned of VERBOSE linking and set it to none. Now I have zip spitting out.